# Getting database $row property by name saved in config file in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to go over `$row` object which I got from the `$this->db->get()->result();`

The table column names are stored in config file, which I can access like this : `$this->tableTask [ 'column' ] [ 'id' ];`

How do I do the following in a single command instead of first assigning the column name to a variable then reaching the $row property ?

> This works.

```
$id = $this->tableTask['column']['id'];
$this->data[$this->tableTask[ 'column']['id']] = $row->$id;
```

> This does not. I get the following error.
>
> **Error Message: Object of class Task could not be converted to string**

```
$this->data[$this->tableTask['column']['id']] = $row->$this->tableTask['column']['id'];
```

*Note: This all is happening inside a method of class Task which is an auxiliary class to a custom library I am working on.*

Comment: check `echo $this->tableTask [ 'column' ] [ 'id' ] ` and see what you r getting.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju It is giving me the correct string.

Comment: are you getting more than 1 row?? and if possible please add more code.

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating your variable like this (notice the "{}" marks):

```
$this->data[$this->tableTask['column']['id']] = $row->{$this->tableTask['column']['id']};
```

If you want to use the property value for obtaining the name of another property you have to encapsulate your your value call.

Comment: Please edit you answer and explain what you are doing.

Comment: Encapsulating {$var} will return the value of var, which is then used as a property name.